# Problems with compiling Intel TBB library

Tags: emscripten

When compiling a project, I get about 20 errors that all relate to the TBB library's. When I compile the project with VS2015, I do not get any errors. About Emsctipten it looks like this. What can this be? Many thanks for the help.

```js
// WITH EMCC

// C:/Users/Admin/Documents/EMC/OpenFace>emcc FaceLandmarkVid.cpp -o OpenFace.js

// C:/Users/Admin/Documents/EMC/OpenFace/3rdParty/tbb/include/tbb/tbb_machine.h:332:6: // error: Unsupported
//      machine word size.
//    #error Unsupported machine word size.

// Code from tbb_machine.h Line: 328 - 333 //

// #define __TBB_CompareAndSwapW(P,V,C)    __TBB_machine_cmpswp8(P,V,C)
// #define __TBB_FetchAndAddW(P,V)         __TBB_machine_fetchadd8(P,V)
// #define __TBB_FetchAndStoreW(P,V)       __TBB_machine_fetchstore8(P,V)
//#else /* __TBB_WORDSIZE != 8 */
//    #error Unsupported machine word size.
//#endif /* __TBB_WORDSIZE */
    
//   20 errors generated.



// WITH CLANG //

// C:/Users/Admin/Documents/EMC/OpenFace>clang++ FaceLandmarkVid.cpp -o OpenFace.js

// C:/Users/Admin/Documents/EMC/OpenFace/3rdParty/tbb/include/tbb/internal
//   /_tbb_windef.h:32:2: error: TBB
//      requires linkage with multithreaded C/C++ runtime library. Choose multithreaded // DLL runtime in project
//      settings, or use /MD[d] compiler switch.
// #error TBB requires linkage with multithreaded C/C++ runtime library. \

//   28 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi haven't tested this on my machine, but you need to look at a wider context (looking at TTB code from https://github.com/jckarter/tbb/blob/master/include/tbb/tbb_machine.h#L285):

```
#if __TBB_WORDSIZE==4
    #define __TBB_CompareAndSwapW(P,V,C)    __TBB_machine_cmpswp4(P,V,C)
    #define __TBB_FetchAndAddW(P,V)         __TBB_machine_fetchadd4(P,V)
    #define __TBB_FetchAndStoreW(P,V)       __TBB_machine_fetchstore4(P,V)
#elif  __TBB_WORDSIZE==8
    #if __TBB_USE_GENERIC_DWORD_LOAD_STORE || __TBB_USE_GENERIC_DWORD_FETCH_ADD || __TBB_USE_GENERIC_DWORD_FETCH_STORE
        #error These macros should only be used on 32-bit platforms.
    #endif

    #define __TBB_CompareAndSwapW(P,V,C)    __TBB_machine_cmpswp8(P,V,C)
    #define __TBB_FetchAndAddW(P,V)         __TBB_machine_fetchadd8(P,V)
    #define __TBB_FetchAndStoreW(P,V)       __TBB_machine_fetchstore8(P,V)
#else /* __TBB_WORDSIZE != 8 */
    #error Unsupported machine word size.
#endif /* __TBB_WORDSIZE */
```

A quick search in the TTB github directory shows this file (https://github.com/jckarter/tbb/blob/0343100743d23f707a9001bc331988a31778c9f4/include/tbb/tbb_machine.h#L78):

```
Prerequisites for each architecture port
    ----------------------------------------
    The following functions and macros have no generic implementation. Therefore they must be
    implemented in each machine architecture specific header either as a conventional
    function or as a functional macro.
    __TBB_WORDSIZE
        This is the size of machine word in bytes, i.e. for 32 bit systems it
        should be defined to 4.
```

So my guess, without investing too much time, is that somewhere in TTB there is aome platform specific code that sets the value of **__TBB_WORDSIZE** that's suitable for that platform...

So, for Emscripten, you could add the following snippet in your code:

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    #define __TBB_WORDSIZE 4
#endif
```

This should get you through your next compile error. Good luck!

#### Edit 1:

#### How can you fix the following errors?

What you need to realise is that Cpp is mostly portable but any code dealing with low level details will require platform-specific implementation details (it could be obvious, but it may help future readers too). Ideally the platform-specific code is kept to a minimum and all in one place.

Pre-processor variables are used to detect what architecture/compiler is used to compile the code and define some platform-specific details. In TTB, typical platform detection pre-processor variables are `#if __MINGW64__ || __MINGW32__`, `#elif _XBOX`, `#elif __linux__ || __FreeBSD__ || __NetBSD__`, and some sample platform-specific details are `TBB_USE_GCC_BUILTINS`, `__TBB_WORDSIZE`, `__TBB_Yield()`...

Back to TTB, a quick search shows that the platform abstraction layer is in **tbb_machine.h** and you should read the comment at the top of the file, available here: https://github.com/jckarter/tbb/blob/0343100743d23f707a9001bc331988a31778c9f4/include/tbb/tbb_machine.h#L32

Make sure that you understand the section **Prerequisites for each architecture port**. In this section you will learn that you need to define several macross, and the first ones in the list are `__TBB_WORDSIZE`, `__TBB_Yield()`, `__TBB_full_memory_fence()` and many more.

Finally, the folder **tbb/include/tbb/machine/** contains several platform-specific header files (gcc, mac, xbox...). You will very likely need to create one for emscripten too. When you do that, bear in mind that it's compile with Clang (which is gcc-compatible) and uses a 32-bit architecture.

#### How can you get help more easily, help the rest of the world, get good karma, and show off your increasing C++/Emscripten expertise?

[Fork](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/) the repository on Github. Create an Emscripten branch and make it work (or at least go as far as you can). Update the readme with the exact instructions to build using Emscripten.

When you're stuck, ask another question here on SO. But this time, link to your github repository. If it takes me 2 minutes to reproduce the error on my machine, I'm much more likely to try it and fix a few errors for you.

Even if you never succeed to fully port it, your effort will be available publicly and someone else may build up on it.

If you manage to finish it, well done! You're now an open-source contributor.
Your next step is to open a pull request to merge it back to the main TTB repository. Your patch will then be reviewed by some experienced engineers in Intel, they'll point out potential issues in your code/approach and you will learn a lot by doing so.

Contributing this back to the main library is good for your employer too, by the way. Once it gets merged into the main repository, they will maintain that port as the library evolves. Others are more likely to use it and improve it too.

Finally, in a few years you may want to change job and go through some interviews. When quizzed about your experience and abilities, something along the following lines should help you standout:

> 3 years ago I ported Intel TTB's library to Emscripten. This was harder than I originally anticipated but I eventually made it work. The patch was then reviewed by 2 senior engineers at Intel and incorporated into the library after the code review. The feedback was humbling but it helped me internalise best practices that I still use today and help increasing the quality of my work.

*I hope that edit is helpful. Some of it may be trivial to you, but hopefully it will help some future readers too. And if it convinces one person to start contributing back to open-source, it will make my day :)*

Comment: This answer addresses the issue with EMCC. For Clang on Windows, you need to realize that clang will us cl.exe, and may need further compiler switches, as described in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#id8. To get more info about the meaning of those compiler switches, you could start reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Comment: `@AntonyG` thank you for help. I was able to solve the problem with `__TBB_WORDSIZE`. But I still get many more mistakes. Can it be that it still needs an extension in the emcc command? For example something like `-D__TBB_TASK_CPP_DIRECTLY_INCLUDED = 1 -MD` ?

Comment: To show all the mistakes, I packed them into a fiddle. (`https://jsfiddle.net/71hcpx2k/1/`)

Comment: @JaDoLo you will need to put in a fair bit of work to make this work. I've added details to my answer to hopefully point you in the right direction. If you follow the advice and get stuck, post a new question and link to it from here and I can have a look. Best of luck!

Comment: `@AntonyG` many thanks for the detailed description A ++, I've now been able to compile everything. I used the following commands: `clang++ FaceLandmarkVid.cpp -MD -MT -LD -E -IC:..\..\lib\local\LandmarkDetector\include -IC:..\..\lib\local\FaceAnalyser\include -IC:..\..\lib\local\GazeAnalyser\include -IC:..\..\lib\local\Utilities\include -IC:..\..\lib\3rdParty\OpenCV3.4\include -IC:..\..\lib\3rdParty\dlib\include -IC:..\..\lib\3rdParty\boost -IC:..\..\lib\3rdParty\boost\boost -IC:..\..\lib\3rdParty\tbb\include -IC:..\..\lib\3rdParty\tbb\include\serial -o OpenFace.js`

Comment: The generated .js contains `376'501` lines of code.

Comment: Great stuff! Did you have to modify the code much to make it work? Just curious ;)

Comment: Yes, there was still a lot to be done. But they got me on the way!!

Comment: @JaDoLo - have you got any more information on what you actually did to get it to compile?  I'm trying the same, and while I have got it to compile there are linker issues when I try to use tbb (in tbbmalloc, I believe)

Comment: I'm just starting down this road myself, it appears Perspective is using TBB with Enscripten https://perspective.finos.org/docs/md/development.html so might get some insights there